# Why does postgresql starts serials from 1?

Tags: postgresql

Title pretty much explains it. I'm using postgres as a database and I don't have any problem with it other than this question: why does postgres start auto-incrementing types: smallserial, serial, bigserial with 1.

Logically, it should start with 0 so it can be used with arrays, lists and such easier.

Is there any logic behind this? Is it same with other databases?

**P.s. I'm using pgAdmin 4 to create tables, so I don't know if that's responsible for the situation. I mean, maybe it would start from 0 if I used pure sql code to create the tables. So please take that into account when answering.**

Comment: 1) It can start with any number you choose [Create Sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) 2) Do not give auto-incremented values meaning, they can have gaps, that can `cycle`(wrap around, if specified). They exist just to generate numbers, generally for use as a `PRIMARY KEY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL:2003 standard defined sequences to start at 1 by default (though you may change the default and define a sequence to start at 0 or another value if you prefer).

This is the same in Oracle, Microsoft SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, DB2, Informix, etc. All the popular SQL databases support some sort of sequence generator or identity column. Though specific implementations and syntax varies (not all conform to the SQL:2003 standard), they all start at 1 by default.

There are other cases in SQL of ordinal numbers starting at 1, for example `ROW_NUMBER()`.

These numbers are not meant to be array indexes, so there is no need to align them to conventional zero-based arrays.

Sequences have even less need to be treated as array indexes, because the values are not guaranteed to be consecutive. They are not row numbers.

Comment: "*These numbers are not meant to be array indexes,*" - but even if they did: in SQL, array indexes start with 1 as well.

Comment: I see, so the main reason is that SQL:2003 standard. And yeah, I know how to change them, it takes 2 steps , I first set the minimum value to -1 then set the current value to -1, if I directly try to set both, it says something similar to "current value cannot be lower than current minimum value". But I was just curious it's normal or not, from a coder's perspective, it makes alot of sense to make it start from 0 but I just wondered if it meant anything on a database manager's point of view. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Well, the SQL:2003 standard codified what had been common practice in Oracle and other mainstream databases for years prior to that.